# Copy and paste from Excel to Power Point in excel table format ("keep source formatting")

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to copy and paste from excel to PowerPoint keeping the excel table format. The table also should be copied to a specific place in powerpoint with a specific font size.
I found out how to copy as a picture. However problem is that you cannot modify the picture later and add a sentence or so. 
I use Microsoft 2007 ;(. I think that is part of the problem. I can only paste it as an "OLEObject".

```
Dim oPPT As PowerPoint.Application

Dim ppTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim ppPlaceholder As PowerPoint.PlaceholderFormat

Dim FirstSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim LastSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

'Open PowerPoint

Set oPPT = New PowerPoint.Application
oPPT.Visible = True
oPPT.Presentations.Open 
"P:\Automotive\JDIE_Automotive\For Sales\QuoteLayout\automaticallygenerated.pptm" 

'copy and paste from excel to PowerPoint

    Worksheets("SalesOutput1").Range("A1:I6").Copy 
       oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
             With oSlide.Shapes(oSlide.Shapes.Count)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Left = 43
            .Top = 470
            .Height = 80
      End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but OLE objects have to be formatted in the source program, not the host. You'll have to make the changes in Excel, then paste to PowerPoint.